# error starts with "execute_process..." when run cmakelists.txt in qt creator

Tags: ros, qtcreator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ubuntu 16.04, and ROS version is Kinetic. I installed by terminal, sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full. qt version is 5.8, qt creator version is 4.3.0. I try to run cmake and build ros project in qt creator environment, but something  is wrong, and i don't know why.

Here's my Cmakelist.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

set(CATKIN_TOPLEVEL TRUE)

set(_cmd "catkin_find_pkg" "catkin" "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
execute_process(COMMAND ${_cmd}
  RESULT_VARIABLE _res
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE _out
  ERROR_VARIABLE _err
  OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
  ERROR_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)
if(NOT _res EQUAL 0 AND NOT _res EQUAL 2)
  string(REPLACE ";" " " _cmd_str "${_cmd}")
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Search for 'catkin' in workspace failed (${_cmd_str}): ${_err}")
endif()

if(_res EQUAL 0)
  set(catkin_EXTRAS_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${_out}/cmake")
  # include all.cmake without add_subdirectory to let it operate in same scope
  include(${catkin_EXTRAS_DIR}/all.cmake NO_POLICY_SCOPE)
  add_subdirectory("${_out}")

else()
  if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH)
    if(NOT "$ENV{CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}" STREQUAL "")
      string(REPLACE ":" ";" CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH $ENV{CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
    endif()
  endif()

  set(catkin_search_path "")
  foreach(path ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
    if(EXISTS "${path}/.catkin")
      list(FIND catkin_search_path ${path} _index)
      if(_index EQUAL -1)
        list(APPEND catkin_search_path ${path})
      endif()
    endif()
  endforeach()

  set(CATKIN_TOPLEVEL_FIND_PACKAGE TRUE)
  => Following line is line 52 I mention later 
    find_package(catkin QUIET
    NO_POLICY_SCOPE
    PATHS ${catkin_search_path}
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH)
  unset(CATKIN_TOPLEVEL_FIND_PACKAGE)

  if(NOT catkin_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "find_package(catkin) failed. catkin was neither found in the workspace nor in the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH. One reason may be that no ROS setup.sh was sourced before.")
  endif()
endif()

catkin_workspace()

file(GLOB_RECURSE EXTRA_FILES */*)
add_custom_target(${PROJECT_NAME}_OTHER_FILES ALL WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} SOURCES ${EXTRA_FILES})
```

This code is not modified, but error code occurs like this:

```
error: execute_process(/usr/bin/python "/home/minominium/catkin_ws/build/catkin_generated/generate_cached_setup.py") returned error code 1 /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:186 (safe_execute_process) /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include) CMakeLists.txt:52 (find_package)
```

Sorry for so long and tired question, but I reeallly need the answer. What should I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264298/error-starts-with-%22execute_process...%22-when-run-cmakelists.txt-in-qt-creator/) by [Minos](https://answers.ros.org/users/30841/minos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-06-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-06-20**:
Is there more to the error message? Have you sourced the setup.bash for your workspace before you run qt creator?

**Comment by [Minos](https://answers.ros.org/users/30841/minos/) on 2017-06-21**:
Thanks for responding, ahendrix. This message is printed when I tried to run cmake with toplevel CMakeLists.txt(in ~/workspace/src). Another message is, when I run cmake with each package's CMakeLists(in ~/workspace/src/package).

**Comment by [Minos](https://answers.ros.org/users/30841/minos/) on 2017-06-21**:
It says
error: By not providing "Findcatkin.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "catkin", but CMake did not find one. Could not find a package configuration file provided by "catkin" with any of the following names:

**Comment by [Minos](https://answers.ros.org/users/30841/minos/) on 2017-06-21**:
catkinConfig.cmake catkin-config.cmake Add the installation prefix of "catkin" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "catkin_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "catkin" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.

**Comment by [Minos](https://answers.ros.org/users/30841/minos/) on 2017-06-21**:
Sorry for dividing, but the reply character limit catches me.

**Comment by [Minos](https://answers.ros.org/users/30841/minos/) on 2017-06-21**:
I sourceed setup.bash by
source "echo /opt/....", "source ~/.bashrc". And catkin_init_workspace is also done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Oh, yeah I see it just now. I figured out how to compile via qt. Thanks alot ahendrix!

[Edit]

Just note. If you want to solve the same problem, just follow the steps in ROS wiki - ROS IDE(Qt Creator). Especially, making a .desktop file is most IMPORTANT to solve that problem.

---

Originally posted by [Minos](https://answers.ros.org/users/30841/minos/) with karma: 41 on 2017-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0